# Angular Jasmine testing zip folder download: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'href')

Tags: angular, testing, jasmine

I am trying to create a test unit for my ExportService, but I have issue with the one regarding the download of a zip folder.
The function takes a Blob as input and triggers the folder download.

I tried following other suggestions, as reported below, but I get this error:

Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'href')

```
describe('Export Service Testing', () => {
  let exportService: ExportService,
    httpTestController: HttpTestingController;

  beforeEach(() => { 
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({ 
      imports: [HttpClientTestingModule],
      providers: [ExportService]
    }); 
    exportService = TestBed.inject(ExportService);
    httpTestController = TestBed.inject(HttpTestingController);
  }); 
 
  fit('should download zip folder ', () => {
    const spyObj = jasmine.createSpyObj('a', ['click']);
    spyOn(document, 'createElement');
    exportService.download(new Blob());
    expect(document.createElement).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    expect(document.createElement).toHaveBeenCalledWith('a');

  });

});
```